# Adding Network Service Account to a domain group

Tags: windows, domain

How would I add the Network Service account of a machine to a domain (controller) group?

Comment: Why do you think this would be a good idea?

Answer (score 3):

Network Service authenticates with the computer's domain account, so you might be able to achieve this by adding the computer to a global group.

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer. Been chasing this answer for the past 4 hours and on and off for the past several months. THIS WORKS.